# Modify one element and find out which surounding elements are affected

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

I want to know if there is an algorithm which does the following:

Imagine you have a point cloud and the points affect each other but the action
from each point to an other is only valid in some radius around this point (locally).

Now remove one point and the local configuration changes.

How is the cheapest way to determine which points are affected from this removement?

Comment: This seems to be known as *range searching* and is supported by data structures such as *range trees* and *kd-trees*.