# What data structure would help find nearby coordinates quickly?

Tags: data-structures, computational-geometry, search-algorithms, search-problem

I need to write a program that does the following:

- Take an input list of objects whose properties include latitude and longitude to, say, 5 decimal places
- Store them in a data structure once
- Provide a "nearby" lookup function that can efficiently return the N closest objects for a given lat/long

Currently, I'm doing the following, which is suboptimal:

- Store all objects in a hash, with array keys like `[integer_latitude, integer_longitude]`
- At search time, find all objects in an arbitrary-sized circle around the target. Eg, if the search is at `[0,0]`, I can get all objects within 1 degree by pulling `[-1,0]`, then `[0,0]`, then `[1,0]`, then `[0,-1]`, etc.
- Order the found objects by actual distance to the target and take the top N

This is obviously inefficient, because often there are many more matches than N.

One improvement could be to examine locations in concentric squares outward from the center: all points 0 degrees from the center, all points 1 degree from the center, 2 degrees, etc, and stop after the first square when I have at least the number of objects needed. Then I could sort those by actual, fine-grained distance and take the top N.

Is there some well-established way of doing this search efficiently?

Comment: Another idea would be to use a tree of geohashes, where the geohash gets longer as you go toward the leaves. You could move to a parent to find "near" objects. But I think this fails when two objects are very close together but just opposite a boundary like the equator.

Comment: Have you read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search ?

Comment: How about dictionary? Or 4 directional linked lists?

Comment: [Closely related question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/38461/modify-one-element-and-find-out-which-surounding-elements-are-affected); the comment applies.

Comment: I think quadtrees might give you a first approximation. They are usually good to explore some part of the plane, as a 2-dimensional counterpart to binary-trees. But I am no expert on that.

Comment: Yes, quad trees are the simplest start.  From the geohash wikipedia article, it sounds like a variation on quadtrees: "...the even bits are taken for the longitude code..., while the odd bits are taken for the latitude code".  Strip off 2 low-order bits to go up a level in the hierarchy.  The idea is to have 2D locality so that you can just retrieve the areas that contain your points (and throw out irrelevant parts from those areas).  Somebody else can chime in about the suitability for this when the points move a lot.

Comment: This isn't an algorithm, but one idea is: do it inefficiently, but do it ahead of time, for all possible queries, and cache the answers for quick lookup. "All possible queries" has to be approximate, but if we divide the world into N squares, every lat/long falls into a square, and we can pre-compute answers for all squares. The only question is "how many squares are needed for enough accuracy" and "how much space would that take". Many squares would be irrelevant for my purposes (eg, ocean) and many would share answers. Seems feasible.

Comment: That actually resembles how you might do it in a Hadoop cluster.  If you add a point A (ie: smallest area) at 01101010, go up one level to 011010 and incrementally aggregate information into that area, then up another to 0110, then 01, then the top.  

In particular, I used this to maintain counters from one area to another (ip addresses A talks to B with higher levels being more subnet masking).  The mapreduce jobs need to update O(lg n) areas when an item is updated; doubling storage use.

Comment: And if you think about it, this probably resembles how Google Earth works.  Average 4 neighboring highest resolution pixels together into another point, and keep going up until you got a single pixel for the earth.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could you could do better than a naive approach - you could use a **k-d tree** data structure.

Clever implementations, such as [sklearn k-d tree](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KDTree.html) do the nearest neighbour lookup in `O(log(n))` which, unless you have a high dimensional and sparse dataset, will work significantly faster than a naive `O(n)` approach.

Answer (score 0):

As well as k-d trees, it's worth knowing about [R-trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree), as these are arguably the most popular data structure for indexing in the GIS world.

R-trees are to k-d trees as B-trees are to binary search trees. Like B-trees, R-trees tend to be very cache efficient, which makes them extremely useful for on-disk data structures as you tend to find in databases.

Answer (score 0):

There are obviously many different data structures out there - you could also use a [cover tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_tree)